# Improve wxPython OnPaint

Tags: python, canvas, wxpython, drawing

I have the following `wx.Window`:

```
class SketchWindow(wx.Window):

  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Window.__init__(self, parent, -1)
    self.SetBackgroundColour('White')
    # Window event binding
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, self.OnIdle)
    # run
    self.Run()

  def OnPaint(self, evt):
    self.DrawEntities(wx.PaintDC(self))

  def DrawEntities(self, dc):
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('Black', 1, wx.SOLID))
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('Green', wx.SOLID))
    # draw all
    for e in self.entities:
      x, y = e.location
      dc.DrawCircle(x, y, 4)

  def OnIdle(self, event):
    self.Refresh(False)

  def Run(self):
    # update self.entities ...
    # call this method again later
    wx.CallLater(50, self.Run)
```

I need to draw on my window a number of circles [0, 2000] every N milliseconds (50 in my example), where at each step these circles may update their location.

The method I wrote works (the circles are anti-aliased too) but it's quite slow.
Is there a way to improve my solution?

Comment: SO is primarily for code that does not work.  Your question might be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, which specializes in improving working code.

Comment: In real-time applications, slow code would be considered code that does not work.    Untimely results are as useless as incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

I think the basic idea for better performance is to *draw* to memory offscreen, then blit the result to the screen. You could use the [BufferedCanvas](http://wiki.wxpython.org/BufferedCanvas) to accomplish this (example given at bottom of link page).

Answer (score 0):

You should better explain why you characterize this as quite slow.  (This code looks like it could be part of a billiard table simulation).  Some time profiling would help you there.  I had to add a lot of code to make your code snippet run, but some quick observations is 1) you probably need a dc.Clear() in your OnPaint() routine or you will get "trails" of all the prior drawn circles. Also, you may be able to use a Buffered DC to get smoother graphic updates, by changing

```
def OnPaint(self, evt):
    self.DrawEntities(wx.PaintDC(self))
```

to

```
 def OnPaint(self, evt):
     self.DrawEntities(wx.BufferedPaintDC(self))
```